# on Firemonkey, How can I combine images?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

[image]

How to do this on Delphi XE 10.1 with FMX?

I'm trying to insert a small image at a desired location on a large image.
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=867027
I tried using an example in this question.
In the first DrawBitmap example
If you set the Rect coordinate value to fit the desired coordinate value, the small image will be cut off.
The second example does not have a method called Draw in FMX TCanvas.
I want to get help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The [**DrawBitmap**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawBitmap) method draws scaled bitmap area described by the **SrcRect** parameter into the canvas area described by the **DstRect** parameter. So you must have used wrong area rectangles. Try this (it draws 50% scaled bitmap onto the canvas 8 pixels from left and top):

```
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  SrcRect: TRectF;
  DstRect: TRectF;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.CreateFromFile('C:\MyImage.bmp');
  try
    SrcRect := Bitmap.BoundsF;

    DstRect := SrcRect;
    DstRect.Width := DstRect.Width / 2;
    DstRect.Height := DstRect.Height / 2;
    DstRect.Offset(8, 8);

    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, SrcRect, DstRect, 100);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```